# How to do an ng-repeat inside the <head> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do an ng-repeat in the `<head>` of a page in order to enumerate open graph meta tags.  However, I'm not sure how to accomplish as it seems that tags allowed in `<head>` are containing tags.

If I simply add a `<div>` wrapper like I often do with ng-repeat, browsers bump it down from the `<head>` down into `<body>`.

I have considered creating my own do-nothing directive to allow me to do something like this

```
<custom-repeat-wrapper ng-repeat="entry in entries">
  <meta property="entry.key" content="entry.content"/>
</custom-repeat-wrapper>
```

I presume that would work, but for all I know, browsers might bump it down to `<body>` as well.

I guess I could potentially write my own directive that sorta works like ng-repeat, but doesn't require a wrapper, and instead duplicates the tag it is placed on.

Anyone have any other suggestions for a cleaner solution before I head down this path?

Comment: Meta tags have no function once the page is loaded in some browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure if it actually is or not, but this seems kind of hacky to be doing in the `<head>`.

Comment: @Chev, <meta> tags are supposed to be placed in the head: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: I meant angular logic, lol

Comment: Thanks for the edits... didn't notice the tags had disappeared.

Comment: @Chev, understood.  I've noticed most angular code and examples scope angular to just the body, but I have already encountered a few situations where I needed angular magic with in the <head>, and it does tend to work as I have needed it to.

Comment: @isherwood, Yes, that can be a problem, but I actually cache the final render of the page for access by search engines and crawlers, so as long as the meta tags have been rendered before the page markup is cached, it suits my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to declare the angular app in the html tag and use the ng-repeat inside the meta tag, like this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head ng-controller="headController">
      <meta ng-repeat="entry in entries" property ="{{entry.key}}" content="{{entry.content}}">
    </head>
</html>
```

And the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('headController', function($scope) {
    $scope.entries = [{
      key: 'key1',
      content: 'content1'
    }, {
      key: 'key2',
      content: 'content2'
    }, ];

  })
```

Here is a working plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ztCTB4mhvyou4ccKVk0u?p=preview

Comment: Yes, yes, yes!  Perfect.  I didn't know you could put it directly on an element and have that element repeated.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @DavidA Not only can you put `ng-repeat` right on a single element and have it repeated, you can also use [`ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points) to repeat a set of elements without nesting them within another element and repeating the container. Very useful for repeating a set of table rows.